# Assembler error in using the f2py tool with a fortran code

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a simple fortran code as follows:

```
    subroutine square_cube(i, isquare, icube)
        integer, intent(in)  :: i
        integer, intent(out) :: isquare, icube
        isquare = i**2
        icube   = i**3
    end subroutine square_cube

    subroutine hellofortran (n)
        integer n

        do 100 i=0, n
            print *, "Fortran says hello"
100     continue
    end subroutine hellofortran

    program xx
        implicit none
        integer :: i, isq, icub
        i = 4
        call square_cube(i, isq, icub)
        print*, "i,i^2,i^3=", i, isq, icub
        call hellofortran (i)
    end program xx
```

This program runs perfectly when I build and run it on Code::Blocks 13.12. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564771/compile-fortran-module-with-f2py?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526632/embedding-fortran-in-python-with-f2py?rq=1) post suggest to change the name of the python module or the extension of the fortran source. I renamed the source with extensions `.f90` and '.f95' and still it does not give errors on Code::Blocks.

I am using Cygwin for all this. When Fortran source is compiled I get a `.o` and a `.exe` file.
When I try to build fortran code using `f2py -c -m fmod test1.f95` I am always getting some assembler errors like:

```
....
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:34: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:35: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:39: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:41: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:43: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:58: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:59: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:62: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:63: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
E:\cygwin64\tmp/cc6Dk38U.s:66: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
....
error: Command "/cygdrive/e/g95/bin/g95 -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O -I/tmp/tmpKd7WH9/src.cygwin-1.7.33-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c -c test1.f95 -o /tmp/tmpKd7WH9/test1.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I have g95 fortran compiler.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do not use version specific tags without the main tag (`fortran`) next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the g95 compiler which was generating a 32 bit code and all other tools that I was using were generating 64 bit code. 
I used gfortran instead of g95 and I got the right output. I had to separately install gfortran using MinGW.